# jQuery update (1.7) breaks event coords on touch event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This jsfiddle reproduces the problem and allows you to quickly switch between `1.6.4` and `1.7.1`.

You'll see that LIs stop being detected, because the coords are `undefined` after switching to `1.7.1`

http://jsfiddle.net/eHHgP/2/

How can I fix this problem without downgrading?

```
body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#other{
position: absolute;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#other ul{
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
right: 50px;
bottom: 50px;
left: 50px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

#other li{
    display: block;
    margin: 25px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    float: left;

<div id="other">
   <ul>
       <li>LI</li>
       <li>LI</li>
       <li>LI</li>
       <li>LI</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="output">
    output
<div>
$(document).bind('touchmove', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();              
});

$('#other').bind('touchstart touchmove', function(event){
    element = document.elementFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY);
    console.log(event);
    if(element.nodeName === 'LI'){
       $('#output').html('LI');
   }else{
       $('#output').html('NOT LI');     
   }    
});
```

Comment: Could you try `event.originalEvent.pageX` instead?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder As far as I know the event object is passed from the dom unmodified, right? I didn't think jQuery should have any effect on it.

Comment: *"I think because the coords are `undefined` with 1.7.1"* Surely you can test that to be sure?

Comment: @fancy: *"As far as I know the event object is passed from the dom unmodified, right?"* No, not at all, jQuery does a lot to it: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ If you want the *raw* event object, it's available as `event.originalEvent`.

Comment: Ah ok, I was told otherwise in #jQuery about the event object. I tested coords awhile ago, let me go make sure that's what is causing it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yep, event.pageX is undefined when switched to 1.7.1

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: In 1.7, only properties which pass the following regexp get a "mouse status" and have their `.pageX` properties etc. passed through to the jQuery event object: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L7. Touch events don't pass this regexp. See also https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L1041.

Comment: @pimvdb How would you achieve example this in 1.7.1 then?

Comment: @fancy: I don't have a touch device to test on, but try setting `jQuery.event.fixHooks["touchstart"] = jQuery.event.mouseHooks;` at the beginning (and do the same for other touch events).

Comment: @pimvdb that hack works, why did they break it though :(

Comment: @pimvdb, was this change made for a reason or did someone just not think about touch events when writing the regex?

Comment: @fancy: I think the latter as I don't see a reason for not supporting those - especially since touch events are becoming more interesting with all new devices.

Comment: @pimvdb Could I monkey patch it? What would the proper regex look like? (maybe you could submit a pull request with this change?)

Comment: @fancy: Perhaps like this: https://github.com/pimvdb/jquery/commits/. I'd need to test it, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that in 1.7, only events which pass [this regexp](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L7) have certain "mouse properties" (like `.pageX`) passed through to the jQuery event object:

```
/^(?:mouse|contextmenu)|click/
```

Obviously, `touchstart` etc. don't pass this regexp. So you'd have to mark these events as being mouse events yourself, as jQuery does [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L1041). You can do it this way if you want to go for conciseness:

```
// add more if necessary, I don't know much about touch events
$.each("touchstart touchmove touchend".split(" "), function(i, name) {
    jQuery.event.fixHooks[name] = jQuery.event.mouseHooks;
});
```

Comment: you were right before, using event.originalEvent.pageX worked on another device. that seems like the way to go. not sure what was up with the first device i tested on.

Comment: @fancy: You should always be able to fall back on `.originalEvent`, since that's the native, "normal" event object, untouched by jQuery.

Comment: hmm, it seems like `touchend` doesn't have the pageX property at least on iPad (I guess since the "mouse" isn't on the screen anymore?). Can anyone confirm?

Comment: If you are using jQuery 3, remove this code or (if you need to support jQuery 1 or 2 as well) only run it if `jQuery.event.fixHooks` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Also another way to handle this is using the proper e.changedTouches. So it would work like this:

```
if (typeof e.changedTouches !== 'undefined') {
  pageX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
  pageY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
} else {
  pageX = e.pageX;
  pageY = e.pageY;
}
```

Hope this helps.